# Unable to import database using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am trying to import database that i created for my website 1 year ago into my new mac but it is giving me this error.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Have you tried what the error itself is suggesting? _"Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error"_

Comment: And please avoid adding textual information as an image. You can read the [list of reasons why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: There is a "root" user attached with your Procedure. You have to change your username or remove the "DEFINER" from the procedure.

Comment: Have your tried running mysql_upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

Since your old database probably has an older version of MySQL you have to execute the following command in the console:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Then enter the root password if necessary.